# Playing sound from account accessed with su or ssh

Tags: sound, ssh, xorg, pulseaudio, su

I have two accounts.  `jamesk` and `other`

I can run X windows applictions using the `other` account in a couple of ways:

1. `ssh -X other@localhost`
2. `xhost +`  followed by `su - other` and the then `export DISPLAY=:0.0`

With either of these I can run, for example `xeyes` and open a window.

However I can't get any sound from the other account.

I'd like to run

```
jamesk$ ssh -X other@localhost
(password)
other@localhost$ ffplay yesterday.mp3
```

I've looked at `paprefs`,  however any attempt to install any of the modules required for network sound cause `paprefs` to crash with `SIGTRAP`

When I do this I don't get any sound played, but I do see the ffplay visualiation of the sound.

Comment: X protocol is transferring only display, not sound. So you won't get any sound from the remote machine using X alone. You need to use something else for that purpose, for example PulseAudio remote sound feature that you mentioned. However, I don't know why it crashes. Maybe this answer helps you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470961/how-to-set-up-pulseaudio-remote-properly-and-securely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the connection you need an open tcp port.

So connect to the second account with `ssh`

```
jamesk$ ssh -R 22753:localhost:4713 -X other@localhost
```

This opens a port for sound.

Then set pulseaudio on the `other` account to use that tcp port

```
other$ export PULSE_SERVER="tcp:localhost:22753"
```

Pulseaudio then connects back through the ssh connection to the main account, where the sound is picked up and played.

This requires the tcp module to be enabled on the main account.
jamesk$ pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-anonymous=1
27
jamesk$ pactl list modules short
...
module-native-protocol-tcp  auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24